# An App for Android Tablets

Tags: android

I am very new to android development. I wanna create a app thats like a ticker on android tablet. But when the user clicks on any other application, i still want my ticker to be visible and the other app to resize and occupy rest of the screen only.

Somebody told me that this is not possible. Is it the case ? Anyone know of any similar app ? or somehow plz get me started with this ?

Thanks for your help.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good idea steal screen space from other applications. If your ticker is floating above like modal window, it would probably block some views for the user.
If your app is competing for the screen space, the other app would probably look ugly.
My suggestion is that you rethink your application, and follow the [user interface guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this isn't possible. Even if, it isn't a good idea. If you want something like that consider creating a widget or some kind of notification. That would be the best and a lot of applications use notifications like that.

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is creating a system type of window,such as PHONE_WINDOW,make your app  flowing on the up-layer of other normal window.

You may read this post
http://www.apkbus.com/android-77789-1-1.html